# How to assign a collection to variable in jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a `HashMap` with signature `savedQuestionAnswer<Integer,ArrayList>`. I am trying to get the `List` for particular key and assigning it to variable and iterating through it using the following code

```
<c:set var="answerList" value="${savedQuestionAnswer[theCount.count]}"/>
<c:forEach var="answers" items="answerList">
 <c:out value="${ answers}" /> <br>
</c:forEach>
```

but it's just printing answerList each time

Answer (score 0):

May be you have missed to write your variable name inside `${..}`.

You could try `${answerList}` instead of `answerList` for `items` attribute like this:

```
<c:forEach var="answers" items="${answerList}">
 <c:out value="${answers}" /><br/>
</c:forEach>
```